# PhoneGap - contacts plugin - images location

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have an issue I cannot find a solution for despite scouring the internet for obvious clues.

I have a very basic PhoneGap app that uses the contacts plugin.

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  // get all contacts
  var options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = "";
  options.multiple = true;
  var filter = ["name", "phoneNumbers", "photos"];
  navigator.contacts.find(filter, onContactSuccess, onError, options);
}


function onContactSuccess(contacts) {
  var element = document.getElementById('contacts');

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    // the following check is incomplete for brevity
    if (contacts[i].photos) {
      // this produces a valid file location
      element.innerHTML += contacts[i].photo[0].value;
      // this renders an image not found square
      element.innerHTML += "<img src='" + contacts[i].photo[0].value + "'>";
    }
  }

}
```

The problem that eludes me is the insertion of the image. PhoneGap serve produces the following error

> [phonegap] 404
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C7B8E714-47EE-42AD-9C58-6B86EE068110/tmp/photo_cXxyI

and yet using iExplore I can see the photo_cXxyI in the /tmp folder.

I'm following the [post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/12/23/cordova-demo-viewing-all-contacts) from Raymond Camden that has a demo of the contacts plugin but my version refuses to show the images.

I'm running the app on the iOS PhoneGap app and there is data being returned (first, last, phone numbers, images array).

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? I did also notice that the temp image files accumulate in the /tmp folder. They don't ever seem to be deleted. Is this a clue or an 'undocumented' feature?